# Anchor links in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to use anchor links on a flutter screen to scroll a listview / customscrollview to a certain spot in a page - similar to using anchor links (a href="#"  a name="") in HTML?

I've searched for code examples or flutter packages but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm understaing clearly that you want to jump to certain index 
there is a simple method [using this package](https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view)

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply build your own anchor logic with .jumpTo(double (vertical Offset value)) method from ScrollController that you can pass to any sliver widget like CustomScrollView.
Then you can write an extension method on widget that registers Offsets of your anchor objects (have to declare globalKeys on them)

```
extension GetOffset on Widget { 
  Offset getOffset() { return this.key.currenContext.findRenderObject().localToGlobal(Offset.zero)}
}
```

then register the offsets in some shared state to be accesible to the ScrollController and then you can programatically jump to certain positions on the scroll view